# Вызывать php при нажатии кнопки

Tags: javascript, php, html, email

Есть код в `mail.php`, который находится в папке `php/mail.php`.

```
<?php

  $to = `myMail@mail.ru`; //моя же почта пока
  $subject = `Подтверждение регистрации`;
  $message = 'Пример письма';

  $message = wordwrap($message, 70, "\r\n");

  mail($to, $subject, $message);
?>
```

И мне нужно, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку

```
<button class='button2' onclick='sendCod()' href='/php/mail.php'>Отправить код на почту</button>
```

Запускался `php` файл. Этот код находится в файле по пути: `js/data/var/text.js`

Подскажите пожалуйста как это сделать, поскольку с php еще не связывался особо.

Comment: сделай через форму, в форме будет кнопка, а на форме запрос

Answer (score 0):

Для этого используется **Ajax**

Примерный код:

```
                $(function () {
                    var data = $(this).serialize();
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "https://example.com/index.php",
                        data: data,
                        success: function (result) {
                             console.log(result)
                            });
                        }
                    });
                });
```

Скрипт выполниться, если скрипт отдаст какой-то текст, он выведется в консоль.

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать через _GET запрос.

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['send'])) {
  $to = `myMail@mail.ru`; //моя же почта пока
  $subject = `Подтверждение регистрации`;
  $message = 'Пример письма';

  $message = wordwrap($message, 70, "\r\n");

  mail($to, $subject, $message);
}
<a href="?send">Send code </a>
?>
```

Когда пользователь нажимает ссылку, обрабатывается запрос "Если использована переменная send тогда делаем это"